# jscrollpane problem with my child theme

Tags: jquery

i am trying to use jscrollpane , but i tried everything , its still not working

this is my function page

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom Child Theme Functions
 *
 * This file's parent directory can be moved to the wp-content/themes directory 
 * to allow this Child theme to be activated in the Appearance - Themes section of the WP-Admin.
 *
 * Included are a set of constants that can be defined to customize aspects of Thematic's 
 * functionality, as well as a sample function that will add a home link to your menu.
 * "Uncomment" or add more to cusomize the functionality of your Child Theme.
 *
 * More ideas can be found in the community documentation for Thematic
 * @link http://docs.thematictheme.com
 *
 * @package ThematicSampleChildTheme
 * @subpackage ThemeInit
 */


// Unleash the power of Thematic's dynamic classes
// 
// define('THEMATIC_COMPATIBLE_BODY_CLASS', true);
// define('THEMATIC_COMPATIBLE_POST_CLASS', true);

// Unleash the power of Thematic's comment form
//
// define('THEMATIC_COMPATIBLE_COMMENT_FORM', true);

// Unleash the power of Thematic's feed link functions
//

// define('THEMATIC_COMPATIBLE_FEEDLINKS', true);


// Adds a home link to your menu
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_page_menu
//function childtheme_menu_args($args) {
//    $args = array(
//        'show_home' => 'Home',
//        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
//        'menu_class' => 'menu',
//        'echo' => false
//    );
//  return $args;
//}
//add_filter('wp_page_menu_args','childtheme_menu_args');
?>
<?php
include("custompost_functions.php");
/* ********************************************** */
/* Remove the standard Thematic menu */
/* ********************************************** */
function remove_menu() {
remove_action('thematic_header','thematic_access',9);
}
add_action('init', 'remove_menu');
// Moving the thematic menu above the header
add_action('thematic_header','thematic_access',6);


/* ********************************************** */
/* Register Menu */
/* ********************************************** */
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
            'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
            'side-menu' => __( 'Side Menu' ),

        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
/* ********************************************** */
/* Footer Menu */
/* ********************************************** */
function footer_menu() {

   if ( has_nav_menu( 'footer-menu' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer-menu',
                'container_class'=>'footer-menu',
                'menu_class' => 'sf-menu', // we assign the sf-menu class to the menu ul so that superfish works on this menu too
                ) );

    }
}

add_action('thematic_footer','footer_menu',41);
function side_menu() {

   if ( has_nav_menu( 'side-menu' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'side-menu',
                'container_class'=>'side-menu',
                'menu_class' => 'side-menu', // we assign the sf-menu class to the menu ul so that superfish works on this menu too
                ) );

    }
}

add_action('thematic_abovemainasides','side-menu');
/* ********************************************** */
/* Footer Social Menu */
/* ********************************************** */
function social_menu(){ ?>
<div class="social">
<ul class="sf-menu">
<li><a href="#">Follow Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/Facebook.png" width="16" height="16" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/Twitter.png" width="16" height="16" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/Skype.png" width="16" height="16" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<?php }
add_action('thematic_footer','social_menu',44);
?>
<?php
/* ********************************************** */
/* Intro Message */
/* ********************************************** */
if(!function_exists('getPageContent'))
{
function getPageContent($pageId,$max_char)
{
if(!is_numeric($pageId))
{
return;
}
global $wpdb;
$nsquery = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ' . $wpdb->posts .
' WHERE ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID=' . $pageId;
$post_data = $wpdb->get_results($nsquery);
if(!empty($post_data))
{
foreach($post_data as $post)
{
$text_out=nl2br($post->post_content);
$text_out=str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text_out);
$text_out = strip_tags($text_out);
return substr($text_out,0,$max_char);

}
}
}
}
/* ********************************************** */
/* REGISTER SCRIPTS */
/* ********************************************** */
    function register_js() {
        if (!is_admin()) {
            wp_deregister_script('jquery');
            wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js');
            wp_register_script('quicksand', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.quicksand.js', 'jquery');
            wp_register_script('easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', 'jquery');
            wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.custom.js', 'jquery', '1.0', TRUE);
            wp_register_script('prettyPhoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', 'jquery');
            wp_register_script('mousewheel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mousewheel.js', 'jquery');
            wp_register_script('jscrollpane', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.jscrollpane.js', 'jquery');


            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
            wp_enqueue_script('quicksand');
            wp_enqueue_script('prettyPhoto');
            wp_enqueue_script('easing');
            wp_enqueue_script('custom');
            wp_enqueue_script('mousewheel');
            wp_enqueue_script('jscrollpane');
        }
    }

    add_action('init', 'register_js');
/* ********************************************** */
/* REGISTER STYLES */
/* ********************************************** */
    function register_styles()
    {
        if (!is_admin()) {
            wp_register_style('prettyPhoto', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/prettyPhoto.css');
            wp_register_style('jscrollpane', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/jquery.jscrollpane.css');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'prettyPhoto');
            wp_enqueue_style( 'jscrollpane');
        }       
    }

    add_action('init', 'register_styles');

/* ********************************************** */
/* Jscrollpane Menu */
/* ********************************************** */

function my_in_head(){  ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //tells WP to recognize the $ variable

    //paste your jquery code here
    $('#content').not('body.home #content').jScrollPane();
    }); //end document ready functions

    /* ]]> */
    </script>

<?php }
add_action('wp_head', 'my_in_head');
/* ********************************************** */
/* Exclude specific post */
/* ********************************************** */

function excludeposts() {
global $wp_query;

    if (is_home()) {
        $defaults = $wp_query->query_vars;
        $exclude = array('category__not_in'=> array(5));
        $args = wp_parse_args( $exclude, $defaults );
        query_posts($args);
    }
}
add_action('thematic_above_indexloop','excludeposts');
/* ********************************************** */
/* Change default content display on home page to excerpt */
/* ********************************************** */
function childtheme_content($content) {
if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {
$content= 'excerpt';}
return $content;
}
add_filter('thematic_content', 'childtheme_content');
/* ********************************************** */
/* Add read more Link  */
/* ********************************************** */
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '<a class="more-link" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more...</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
/* ********************************************** */
/* Dynamic sidebar for each page template  */
/* ********************************************** */
function is_pagetemplate_active($pagetemplate = '') {
global $wpdb;
$sql = "select meta_key from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key like '_wp_page_template' and meta_value like '" . $pagetemplate . "'";
$result = $wpdb->query($sql);
if ($result) {
return TRUE;
} else {
return FALSE;
}
} // is_pagetemplate_active()

function test_template_widgets_init() {    
    if(is_pagetemplate_active('template-page-test.php')) {

        register_sidebar( array (
            'name' => 'Test Widget Area',
            'id' => 'test-widget-area',
            'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => "</li>",
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
        ) );

    } // end test for active template
} // test_template_widgets_init()
add_action ( 'init' , 'test_template_widgets_init' );?>
```

do i register jquery and scripts correctly ? or i miss something ?
Thanks

Comment: No - please don't un-register jQuery and then re-register via Google. Right now the version on Google is 1.8.0 - which jscrollpane is not compatible with. I'd separate out your appearance logic into your theme and site logic into plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it like that and its working now

```
function kia_enqueue_scripts() {

    //use google's jquery
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js');

    //load up your own plugin
    wp_enqueue_script('easing', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.custom.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('mousewheel', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mousewheel.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jscrollpane', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.jscrollpane.js');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kia_enqueue_scripts');
```